# Flutter não retorna imagens da api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, flutter, dart

Eu to tentando pegar as imagens do banco dados mongodb, via api que fiz em nodejs, mas não funciona de jeito nenhum, e ainda apresenta esse erro aqui.

```
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///1573130697077_login_enabled.PNG

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl  (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2191:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl  (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2122:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync 
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:84
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      NetworkImage.load 
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("1573130697077_login_enabled.PNG", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("1573130697077_login_enabled.PNG", scale: 1.0)
```

Pelas várias pesquisas que eu fiz, eu percebi que eu to pegando apenas a imagem, em vez de pegar o endereço dela. Tentei passar esse endereço de várias formas, mas mesmo assim não consegui.

Estarei passando logo abaixo todos os códigos envolvidos:

no node tá assim:

```
var date = new Date();
    time_stamp = date.getTime();


    var url_imagem = time_stamp + '_' + req.files.caminho_foto.originalFilename;

    var path_origem = req.files.caminho_foto.path;
    var path_destino = './images/' + url_imagem;

    fs.rename(path_origem, path_destino, function(err){
        if(err){
            res.status(500).json({error: err});
            return;
        }

    async function salvaMedico(){
        const medicos = new Medicos({
            nome: req.body.nome,
            formacao: req.body.formacao,
            crm: req.body.crm,
            cidade: req.body.cidade,
            caminho_foto: url_imagem
            //data_atualizacao: null
            });
```

e no flutter

```
Container(
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
                    child: new Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      child: Image.network(
                        snapshot?.data[index]?.caminhoFoto ?? '',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover
                      ),
```

Esse último código tá dentro de um Listview que está dentro de um FutureBuilder.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso resolver isso?

Comment: `No host specified` acho que precisa de um hostname e provavelmente senha para funcionar. fiz uma API em json e tentei puxar por nodeJS, e apresentou esse mesmo erro

Comment: Consome sua API por algum outro cliente (browser, postman, etc). Pegue a URL que ela retorna e tente acessar, se não funcionar assim, o problema não é do flutter.

Comment: @JulioHenriqueBitencourt tanto no postman quanto no browser retorna os dados

Comment: @riki481 como conseguiu resolver?

Comment: retorna os dados, mas que dados retorna exatamente? Você consegue pegar essa URL e acessar pelo browser?

Comment: @JulioHenriqueBitencourt retorna no formato JSON

Comment: @LocalizaMed você não precisa desfazer as alterações realizadas por alguém em sua pergunta, se modifiquei a mesma é para deixá-la mais limpa.

Comment: Poderia utilizar um print para mostrar o que retorna do snapshot.data[].caminhoFoto ? Preciso saber também como você chama o webservice e o que ele retorna no atributo 'caminhoFoto'

Comment: @LocalizaMed eu sei que obviamente retorna um JSON... O que eu te perguntei foi o valor exato retornado no campo, e se copiando essa URL (que eu suponho que seja uma URL em um formato válido que sua API está retornando), você consegue colar no navegador e ter acesso a essa imagem.

Comment: @LocalizaMed este é o problema, não consegui resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o erro que você disponibilizou, você está tentando acessar uma imagem que não existe em seu dispositivo.

> Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///1573130697077_login_enabled.PNG

Utilizando apenas o nome da sua imagem, seu servidor consegue acessa-la pois ambos estão no mesmo local, já seu celular não.

Então para abrir a imagem que está no seu BD, pelo seu celular, primeiro você terá que baixar ela no seu celular, segue abaixo uma forma de se fazer:

**EXEMPLO**

**No seu servidor (Utilizarei o Express)**

Crie uma rota de dowload

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  const file = `${__dirname}/imagens/sua_image.png`;
  res.download(file);
});
```

Fontes: [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download); [StackOverflowEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express)

**Em sua aplicação**

Crie um método que irá fazer acesso a sua nova rota e baixar a imagem utilizando o [package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader#-readme-tab-).

Comando do package utilizado para baixar a imagem:

```
await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url);
```

Fontes: [StackOverflowEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299112/flutter-download-an-image-from-url)

Após ter a imagem baixada, utilize o caminho dela para exibir em seu widget.

*~~ Não cheguei a realizar testes com os exemplos, estou sem Flutter e NodeJS no momento ~~*

Comment: funcionou. Eu só precisei criar uma nova rota para pegar as imagens. Obrigado ^^